# PHP - Why does my computation produce a different result when I assign it to a variable?

Tags: php

I want to round a number to a specific number of significant digits - basically I want the following function:

```
round(12345.67, 2) -> 12000
round(8888, 3) -> 8890
```

I have the following, but there's a strange problem.

```
function round_to_sf($number, $sf) 
{
 $mostsigplace = floor(log10(abs($number)))+1;
 $num = $number / pow(10, ($mostsigplace-$sf));

 echo ($number / pow(10, ($mostsigplace-$sf))).' '.$num.'<BR>';
}

round_to_sf(41918.522, 1);
```

Produces the following output:

```
4.1918522 -0
```

How can the result of a computation be different when it's assigned to a variable?

Comment: Perhaps you are not running the code you think you are. When I run the code above I see: "4.1918522 4.1918522<BR>"

Comment: i don't know whether this is relevant, but the function round_to_sf seems to be accepting 3 arguments but the function call seems to be calling with only 2 parameters... Maybe im wrong :(

Comment: I get >Warning: Missing argument 3 for round_to_sf(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\playground\test.php on line 10 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\playground\test.php on line 2
4.1918522 4.1918522<BR>

Comment: @Ranhiru: That was a bad copy/paste on my part - fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the commenting-out binary search method of debugging, I narrowed this down.

Apparently the following line, in another function, in a totally different file even, is the problem.

```
$diff = date_diff(new DateTime($lastdate), new DateTime("NOW"));
```

If I comment that out, I get a correct result from my rounding function.

Can anyone tell me what the .... is going on here? This had me ripping my hair out for a day. It also caused other bugs that looked like memory stomps - I'd run a calculation that should produce a float `foo`, and `foo` would get used in other calculations that produced correct output, but echoing `foo` would show `A.KIPGGGGGGGGG`.